# Downloading file with curl fails when called through xargs

Tags: curl, jq, xargs, msys2

I am using curl to download a file from [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/). I am on windows 10 using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

```
curl --version
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-msys) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1d zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.40.0
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS brotli Debug GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP TrackMemory UnixSockets
```

```
xargs --version
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0
...

which xargs
xargs is an external : C:\msys64\usr\bin\xargs.exe
```

This is my command:

```
curl "http://artifactory.xxx.xxx.com:8080/artifactory/api/storage/generic-tools/xxx-xxx/?lastModified" | jq .uri | xargs curl
```

Curl downloads the json file and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) extract the url for the json file containing with the library information.
However the second curl call fails with:

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Changing the xargs command to `xargs echo curl` gives the expected output. When running this debug output on the command line the correct file is downloaded without any errors.

I can also create a config file that can download the json file:

```
echo.|set /P =URL =  > latest.txt
curl ... | jq .uri >> latest.txt
curl --config latest.txt
```

Why is the piped xargs command not working but the command line command as well as the config file option is working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows binary from the JQ homepage follows the DOS End Of Line conventions and uses CRLF. the `xargs` binary from MSys2 might expect Unix convention for EOLs which is just LF. So `curl` sees an additional stray CR character which it assumes to be part of the URL.

Check that theory by using something like this and check for stray CR (0x0d) characters **between** two URLs:

```
jq '.uri' input.json  |xargs  echo | hexdump -C
```

```
00000000  68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 65  78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 63  |http://example.c|
00000010  6f 6d 2f*0d*20 68 74 74  70 3a 2f 2f 65 78 61 6d  |om/. http://exam|
00000020  70 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2f  0d 0a                    |ple.com/..|
0000002a
```

Comment: Just added `| dos2unix |` between `jq` and `xargs` and problem solved.