# jq bash variable is showing incomplete value

Tags: bash, jq

I have a JSON file and want to copy modules array into a bash variable.
The problem I am trying to solve is I have two dependencies (similar) as below. It has modules array in each. I want to merge these two modules arrays.

```
base_dependencies.txt

{
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "name": "test",
    "number": "1990",
    "buildAgent": {
        "name": "GENERIC",
        "version": "2.16.4"
    },
    "agent": {
        "name": "jfrog-cli-go",
        "version": "2.16.4"
    },
    "started": "2022-05-20T15:01:48.827-0500",
    "durationMillis": 0,
    "artifactoryPrincipal": "test",
    "modules": [{
        "properties": {},
        "type": "generic",
        "id": "test",
        "artifacts": [{
            "type": "jar",
            "sha1": "bef8dd3",
            "sha256": "1c2ba8cb5369d",
            "md5": "f60031d2a0ef13dd8505b61af90c1c44",
            "name": "test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar",
            "path": "libs-release-local/libs7/test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar"
        }]
    }]
}
```

When i run

```
jq '.modules[]' base_dependency.txt
```

i am getting following output

```
    {
  "properties": {},
  "type": "generic",
  "id": "test",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "type": "jar",
      "sha1": "bef8dd3",
      "sha256": "1c2ba8cb5369d",
      "md5": "f60031d2a0ef13dd8505b61af90c1c44",
      "name": "test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar",
      "path": "libs-release-local/libs7/test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying to assign the this to a variable so that i can merge both the variables.

```
base_modules=$(echo | jq '.modules[]' base_dependency.txt )
```

But when i echo base_modules in git bash

```
$ echo $base_modules
 }path": "libs-release-local/libs7/test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar"
```

What am doing wrong.

Comment: Try to run `printf "%q\n" "$base_modules"` and paste result.

Comment: This is one reason why you need to quote your variables: `echo "$base_modules"`

Comment: Watch out for the file's name. Is it `base_dependency.txt` or `base_dependencies.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output `}path":`  makes me think, that this is -- once again -- a DOS/Unix EOL mismatch where a Windows `jq` executable is called from a Git4Windows/Cygwin/WSL `bash`.

Try if this works:

```
base_modules=$(jq '.modules[]' base_dependency.txt | dos2unix)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72296242/947357 for a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem you've described. If I start with your `base_dependencies.txt` file, and run:

```
$ base_modules=$(echo | jq '.modules[]' base_dependencies.txt )
```

I get:

```
$ echo $base_modules
{ "properties": {}, "type": "generic", "id": "test", "artifacts": [ { "type": "jar", "sha1": "bef8dd3", "sha256": "1c2ba8cb5369d", "md5": "f60031d2a0ef13dd8505b61af90c1c44", "name": "test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar", "path": "libs-release-local/libs7/test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar" } ] }
```

Or with quotes:

```
$ echo "$base_modules"
{
  "properties": {},
  "type": "generic",
  "id": "test",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "type": "jar",
      "sha1": "bef8dd3",
      "sha256": "1c2ba8cb5369d",
      "md5": "f60031d2a0ef13dd8505b61af90c1c44",
      "name": "test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar",
      "path": "libs-release-local/libs7/test-0-SNAPSHOT16.jar"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Note that the command you're using to set `base_modules` doesn't need
that `echo`; it should be:

```
$ base_modules=$(jq '.modules[]' base_dependencies.txt )
```

Comment: it is strange when i use "echo $base_modules" i am getting the problem i mentioned. If i embed $base_modules in double quotes, then it is working.